# Wait batch script till CURL finishes execution

Tags: batch-file, curl

I have a CURL which when run on cmd line runs fine and wait till the download completes. If I pass this in a batch file it runs for a second and exits. I am trying to figure out a way for batch to stay till CURL finishes execution. Any idea?

```
 Code removed due to limitation of execution. Unable to remove the question itself. Sorry
```

Comment: Replace `curl` to `curl.exe` and change current directory to its location before execution. At least you'll be sure that you're running the proper executable.

Comment: Tried running from the batch location also changed to curl.exe but still runs for a second and goes like below

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   196  100   196    0     0    165      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   165
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Why you're thinking that the download is not complete?

Comment: Ok, I've just tried your command line and it gives me `curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure`. Seems that something is wrong with SSL on the server...

Comment: Because when I run directly this runs for around 4 minutes to download the file.. I will check for any SSL  related info and will update shortly.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Authentication is happening way later than SSL connection has established so that's not a reason. The reason was because the version of curl I have is pretty outdated. With a fresh version there's no error about SSL. BTW  the page is available for everyone but it's pretty slow. Probably OP's curl stopped by timeout...

Comment: montonero and Gerhard thanks for your help.. Seems syntex error with % symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have percentage signs in the URL. You need to double them in a batch-file i.e. `%` replaced with `%%`.

Comment: thanks michael this works. I didn't checked the % symbol since this was inside a URL